# Missing Descendent in C# Linq

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have following code to read/parse xml. Sometimes xml will not have "COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS" tag. At that time, I am getting some exception related to object. How to check before read the descendent?

```
 var query1 = xmlFile.Descendants("DATA-OBJECT-PROP").Select(level3 => new
            {
                DopID = level3.Attribute("ID").Value,
                DOPShortName = level3.Element("SHORT-NAME") == null ? "" : level3.Element("SHORT-NAME").Value,
                DOPLongName = level3.Element("LONG-NAME") == null ? "" : level3.Element("LONG-NAME").Value,
                //Category = level3.Element("COMPU-METHOD").Element("CATEGORY") == null ? "" : level3.Element("COMPU-METHOD").Element("CATEGORY").Value,
                CompuMethod =level3.Descendants("COMPU-METHOD").Select(x=> new {
             Category=x.Element("CATEGORY").Value,                        
CompuIntToPhys = level3.Descendants("COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS").Select(y=> new{
                            CompuScales=y.Descendants("COMPU-SCALES").Select(a=> new{
                                CompuRationalCoef=a.Descendants("COMPU-RATIONAL-COEFFS").Select(b=> new{
                                    CompuNumerator=b.Descendants("COMPU-NUMERATOR").Select(c=> new Item{
                                        v1 = c.Elements("V").Select(d=> d.Value).ToList()
                                    }),
                                    CompuDenominator = a.Descendants("COMPU-DENOMINATOR").Select(e => new
                                    {
                                        demoni = e.Element("V")
                                    }),
                                })
                            })
                        })
                }),
                phyType=level3.Descendants("PHYSICAL-TYPE").Select(pt=>new {
                    baseDataType=pt.Attribute("BASE-DATA-TYPE").Value,
                    precision=pt.Element("PRECISION").Value
                }),
                interConst = level3.Descendants("INTERNAL-CONSTR").Select(ic => new
                {
                    lowerLimit=ic.Element("LOWER-LIMIT").Value,
                    upperLimit=ic.Element("UPPER-LIMIT").Value
                }),
                unitRef = level3.Element("UNIT-REF").Attribute("ID-REF").Value
            });
```

XML:

```
<DATA-OBJECT-PROP ID="DOP_UI">
                            <SHORT-NAME>DOP_UINT/SHORT-NAME>
                            <LONG-NAME>DEC</LONG-NAME>
                            <COMPU-METHOD>
                                <CATEGORY>IDEN</CATEGORY>
                            </COMPU-METHOD>
                            <DIAG-CODED-TYPE  BASE-DATA-TYPE="A_UI">
                                <BIT-LENGTH>7</BIT-LENGTH>
                                <BIT-MASK>7FA</BIT-MASK>
                            </DIAG-CODED-TYPE>
                            <PHYSICAL-TYPE BASE-DATA-TYPE="A_U2" />
                            <INTERNAL-CONSTR>
                                <LOWER-LIMIT>0</LOWER-LIMIT>
                                <UPPER-LIMIT>127</UPPER-LIMIT>
                            </INTERNAL-CONSTR>
                        </DATA-OBJECT-PROP>
```

Comment: Why not `ComputIntToPhys = level3.Descendants("COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS") == null ? null : level3.Descendants("COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS").Select(....`?  A bit ugly, but should work.

Comment: @Tim I think it will return an empty list instead of null

Comment: You are not getting the exception due to missing "COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS".  The exception is probably due to one of its children.  This type error is normal on the items that have '.Value'.  So replace ic.Element("LOWER-LIMIT").Value  with (string)ic.Element("LOWER-LIMIT")

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with all the suggestions provided above and getting exception like "Processor reference object not set to instance of an object" . It seems some where getting NullReferenceException. But not sure what is the exact root cause for this prob? I have attached the xml snippet (above) for referece which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) :

```
CompuIntToPhys = level3.Descendants("COMPU-INTERNAL-TO-PHYS")
                       .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)
                       .Select(y => new { // ...
```

This method returns

> an IEnumerable that contains *defaultValue* if source is empty;
>   otherwise, *source*.

If the xml file contains this tag, the query remains intact, if it doesn't, `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)` will return singleton `IEnumerable<T>` with some special value that you supply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with all the suggestions provided above and getting exception like "Processor reference object not set to instance of an object" . It seems some where getting NullReferenceException. But not sure what is the exact root cause for this prob? I have attached the xml snippet for referece which is causing the issue.

Comment: It has to be something with the object that you provide (default value), it's possible because in this case  it's a complicated `XElement`. You have to carefully check all the properties of your anonymous object, it's definitely somewhere within the `Select`.